# How do I interpret this difference in matrix multiplication GFLOP/s?

Tags: performance, x86, matrix-multiplication, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm trying some matrix multiplication optimizations from this wiki [here](https://github.com/flame/how-to-optimize-gemm/wiki). While measuring the GFLOP/s for the naive, triple-for-loop matmul, I expected to see a drop in the GFLOP/s after a particular size, which according to the wiki, represents the point where data stops fitting in the cache:

[image: expected_gflops_drop]

I ran the benchmark on 2 different PCs:

- **3rd gen Intel i5 (3210M)**: (L1=32KB per core, L2=256KB per core, L3=3MB shared). 
  I got the expected graph, with a sharp drop from ~2GFLOP/s to 0.5.
- **6th gen Intel i7 (6500U)**: (L1=32KB per core, L2=256KB per core, L3=4MB shared)
  On this, I instead see a gradual decrease in GFLOP/s, even if I try for larger sizes. Looking at the Ubuntu system monitor, one of the CPU cores was always at 100% usage.

[image]

**I'm trying to understand the following:**

1. How do I interpret the change in GFLOP/s with matrix size? If the expected drop corresponds to the data no longer fitting in the cache, why do I not see such a drop even for much bigger sizes on the i7?
2. How does the 3rd gen i5 perform faster for smaller sizes?
3. How do I interpret the CPU occupancy? Would I see a reduction in CPU usage if more time was being spent in fetching data from cache/RAM?

**Edit:**
I switched to `double` from `float` and tried `-O3` and `-O0`, here are the plots. I couldn't check frequencies on the odler i5 but the Skylake i7 goes to turbo freq almost instantaneously for most of the process' duration.
Code from [here](https://github.com/flame/how-to-optimize-gemm), used GCC 7.4.0 on i7, and clang(Apple LLVM 7) on i5.

[image: with_O3]
[image: with_O0]

Comment: Good question, but it would take a substantial amount of microarchitectural analysis to answer.

Comment: Right, I understand a definite answer might depend on many variables. But I just want to know whether my observations make sense, particularly wrt question 1, and what possible factors relate to 2 & 3.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question 2:
While both CPUs have the same base and turbo frequency, the Ivy Bridge has a TDP of 35W while the Skylake has 15W. Even with a much newer process it is possible that the Ivy Bridge is able to use its turbo for a bigger part of the calculation. (Peter Cordes already mentioned checking the actual turbo.).

Regarding question 3:
CPU utilization doesn't depend on what the CPU is doing, waiting for RAM still counts as utilized. There are performance counters you can query which would tell you if the Ivy Bridge is slower because it stalls for memory more often.

Comment: But countering that, Skylake is significantly more power-efficient, so it might still be able to turbo for most of the time in a naive matmul that doesn't auto-vectorize.  But good point that without controlling for total runtime, turbo could be a big factor.  And yeah, the IvB spikes in the L2-bound region might be from getting lucky with turbo, where SKL doesn't have the power / cooling budget to do that.

Answer (score 1):

With efficient cache-blocking, dense matmul should bottleneck on ALU, not memory bandwidth.  O(N^3) work over O(N^2) memory.

But you're measuring a *naive* matmul.  That means it's always horrible if you're striding down columns of one input.  This is the classic problem for cache-blocking / loop-tiling.

Your Skylake has significantly better bandwidth to L3 cache and DRAM, and less-associative L2 cache (4-way instead of 8-way).  Still, I would have expected better performance when your working set fits in L2 than when it doesn't.

SKL probably also has better HW prefetching, and definitely a larger out-of-order window size, than IvyBridge.

IvyBridge (including your 3210M) was the generation that introduced next-page hardware prefetching, but I think the feature with that name is just TLB prefetching, not data.  It probably isn't a factor, especially if transparent hugepages are avoiding any TLB misses.

But if not, TLB misses might be the real cause of the dropoff on IvB.  **Use performance counters to check.**  (e.g. `perf stat`)

---

Was your CPU frequency shooting up to max turbo right away and staying there for both CPUs?  @idspispopd's answer also makes some good points about total power / cooling budget, but yeah check that your two systems are maintaining the same CPU frequencies for this.  Or if not, record what they are.

You did compile with optimization enabled, right?  If not, that could be enough overhead to hide a memory bottleneck.  Did you use the same compiler/version/options on both systems?  Did you use `-march=native`?

Comment: I'll check the CPU frequencies again.

I tried g++ with both, `- O0` and  `-Ofast`, got similar results; I didn't specify `-march`. I should point out that the sandy bridge is an old Mac and the Skylake is running Ubuntu so the compiler versions are different.

Comment: @Manas: Macs typically and confusingly install clang as `gcc`.  That could make a huge difference vs. actual GCC because of loop unrolling.  Anyway, are the numbers in your question from `-O0` or `-Ofast`?

Comment: I updated the numbers for `-O3` instead of `-Ofast` & the frequency. Does this give any insight, or should I check with clang on both?

Comment: @Manas: the same version of clang for both would be preferable.  Or if you can use a compatibility layer to run the same binary on both that would be much better.  Or `objconv` or `objcopy` or something to copy the machine code for the matmul function from a MachO64 object file to ELF64.  Or just copy the asm compiler output from `-S -O3` for the matmul function, and compile that + your main caller on the other machine.  Going both ways to get four data sets on one plot would be neat, but if you only go one way probably the clang version would be more interesting (because it unrolls by default

Comment: Also worth trying: `gcc -O3 -fprofile-generate -fwhole-program *.c` / run it / `gcc -O3 -fprofile-use  -fwhole-program *.c` to enable profile-guided optimization.  (GCC will unroll hot loops in that case).  But seeing the same machine code for the hot loop on both machines would be most interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But what am I looking for here? Is this to answer why my Skylake runs slower for smaller sizes, or why it doesn't slow down for larger sizes? I'm more confused about the latter since I expected it would drop eventually. Will this be affected by loop unrolling?

Comment: @Manas: I don't know what we'll see.  It's possible we'll see Skylake run significantly faster for small sizes if loop unrolling removes a CPU bottleneck that was previously the bottleneck.  L2->L1d bandwidth in Skylake is significantly better than IvyBridge, I think.  Or if clang is unrolling over 4 outer-loop iterations or something, that might give us 4 contiguous accesses in each column or something.  But if that was the case, you'd expect that the largest sizes would have IvB like 3 or 4x faster than SKL.  I just want an apples to apples (or Apple to Apple?) comparison as a first step.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196515/discussion-between-manas-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: @Manas: Since you didn't see any difference when running the clang asm on the other machine, I'd guess that Skylake just has so much more single-core cache / memory bandwidth that it can mostly keep up even beyond L2 size.  Also, having 4-cycle instead of 3-cycle FP-add latency means that the CPU bottleneck is worse.  (Although OoO exec can find some overlap between the end of one outer loop and the start of the next.  Like in the no-lfence case for [Understanding the impact of lfence on a loop with two long dependency chains, for increasing lengths](//stackoverflow.com/q/51986046))